# Teamcity CI build nunit test not reading app.config file

Tags: c#, nunit, city

I have a teamcity install that runs a series of unit tests. I added an app.config file so that the library being tested can pull test config data. This works well when using the nunit GUI on my dev box. On the CI server however the n-unit tests fail because the app.config file is not being read. Is there something I need to do in team city to make this work?

I don't want to change the code or use injection since this is a basic unit testing suite and a significantly large code base.

Comment: solved this with an app config file in the unit testing project, apparently ununit can read an app.config file through the ConfigurationManager object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was able to solve this problem by using an App.config in my unit test project. It is a shame that nunit can't read the config data from another project when being run on a build server. It does this on my local with the nunit runner app on my local no problem!